# How to delete the selected rows from the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a 121 rows × 20 columns dataframe
I want to delete the rows from the picture below
[image: selected rows]

I had tried :

```
sv.drop(sv[(sv['Visit_Duration'] == 'Never')  &  (sv['Visit_Plan'] == 'never')].index,axis=1)
```

It turned out
[image: error]

SO I tried

```
sv.drop(labels=[44,67,107,108,112],axis=0)
```

BUT the result are the same as the original dataframe with  121 rows x 20 columns

Comment: How about use `.where()` function of DataFrame instead? you can filter data with condition.  https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why even delete them? Just filter them out. You want to keep the rows that don't satisfy the conditions you specified here, so you want the negation of `A&B`, which is `~A|~B`:

```
sv = sv[(sv['Visit_Duration'] != 'Never')  |  (sv['Visit_Plan'] != 'never')]
```

or equivalently (`~(A&B)`),

```
sv = sv[~((sv['Visit_Duration'] == 'Never')  &  (sv['Visit_Plan'] == 'never'))]
```

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there, you forget to reassign the result to the dataframe variable.

Try instead:

```
sv = sv.drop(labels=[44,67,107,108,112],axis=0)
```

Or you can also use the `inplace=True` argument for the `drop` function.

```
sv.drop(labels=[44,67,107,108,112], axis=0, inplace=True)
```

Comment: I think this is a better answer because with the other one, if you do further operations on the result, you're subjected to the *SettingWithCopyWarning*. With this answer, that won't happen because `drop` returns anew frame.

Comment: Is it ok if i add .copy() behind like   sv = sv[(sv['Visit_Duration'] != 'Never')  |  (sv['Visit_Plan'] != 'never')].copy() ?